# Google spreadsheet auto timestamp: I don't want timestamp when I delete cell content

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

When I try to delete the content of the cell that the script check, the script paste a new time stamp. I need to only use the script when I write a new value, not when I delete the value.

```html
function onEdit() {
  
  var COLUMNTOCHECK = 1;
  var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,1];
  var SHEETNAME = 'STOCKOUT' 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) { 
      var balance = sheet.getRange("i1").getValue();
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue([balance]);
      }
  }
```

Here's an example:

When I update column A and C, and I try to delete A, B, C, I, script it will run and paste a new value on column B
[Google Spreadsheet Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NH69OjSFw6O76krhjltFlx2VtwYp4KzzHXvRSLq4Xmg/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? When a value is deleted from a cell, the event object `e` of `onEdit(e)` has `e.value.oldValue`. Using this, your script can be written as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function onEdit(e) { // Modified
  if (!e.value.oldValue) { // Added
    var COLUMNTOCHECK = 1;
    var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,1];
    var SHEETNAME = 'STOCKOUT' 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
      var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
        if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) { 
        var balance = sheet.getRange("i1").getValue();
        var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
        dateTimeCell.setValue([balance]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

I thought 3 situations for editing a cell.

1. A value is put to the empty cell.

   - `e.value` is included in the event object.

     - `oldValue` is not included in `e.value`.
   - `e.oldValue` is not included in the event object.
2. The existing value of cell is edited.

   - `e.value` and `e.oldValue` are included in the event object.

     - `oldValue` is not included in `e.value`.
3. The value is deleted from a cell.

   - `e.value` and `e.oldValue` are included in the event object.

     - `oldValue` is included in `e.value`.

I thought that the pattern 3 can be used for OP's situation.

Comment: Did you mean to write "`e.value.oldValue`"? Perhaps "`e.value` and `e.oldValue`" was your intention?

Comment: @tehhowch I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? In the OP's situation, OP doesn't want to run the script when the value is deleted. I thought that the situation 3 is suitable for OP's situation. So I proposed ``if (!e.value.oldValue) {}``. If I misunderstand your comment, I apologize.

Comment: I guess I learned something today, since I did not know that `e.value` would have object type for a cell content deletion. Seems like you're missing a property guard though, as for certain edits `e.value` is undefined and thus cannot be accessed for property `oldValue`.

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you for replying. ``e.value`` is included in above 3 situations. So I used only ``!e.value.oldValue``. If there are the situations that the event object has no property of ``value``, ``e.value && !e.value.oldValue`` is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {  
  if( e.range.getSheet().getName()=='STOCKOUT' && e.range.columnStart==1) {
      e.range.offset(0,1).setValue((e.value)?e.range.getSheet().getRange("I1").getValue():'');
  }else{
    return;
  }
}
```

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)